# SharePoint 2010 & "Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation." & SPListItems.RoleAssignments

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I'm receiving an error when my code attempts to iterate through the `SPListItems.RoleAssignments` collection in my event receiver. But only for users who have contributor rights. Users who have administrator rights.

I've tried the following:

1. Wrapping my under SPRunElevatedPrivlages
2. Windows Impersation using the following code:

   ```
   WindowsImpersonationContext ctx = null;
   ctx = WindowsIdentity.Impersonate(System.IntPtr.Zero);
   SPUserToken oSysToken = GetSysToken(properties.SiteId)
   private static SPUserToken GetSysToken(Guid SPSiteID)
   {
       SPUserToken sysToken = null;
       using(SPSite oSite = new SPSite(SPSiteID))
       {
           sysToken = oSite.SystemAccount.UserToken;
       }
       if (sysToken == null)
       {
           SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(
           delegate()
           {
               using(SPSite site = new SPSite(SPSiteID))
               {
                   sysToken = site.SystemAccount.UserToken;
               }
           });
       }
       return sysToken;
   }
   ```
3. Finally I've tried `SPWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;`

I've try all method seperatly and collective together and nothing. It seems like its through an exception as well on `SPListItems.RoleAssignments.Count`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Users need at least *Manage Permissions* rights on the object to read and modify the `SPSecurableObject.RoleAssignments`.

In order to execute code with system account (elevated) privileges on a SharePoint object you have to "re-open the given object":

```
SPListItem item = // the item from the event receiver

// Re-open the item with the system account
using (SPSite adminSite = new SPSite(item.Web.Url, SPUserToken.SystemAccount))
{
  using (SPWeb adminWeb = adminSite.OpenWeb())
  {
    SPListItem adminItem = adminWeb
      .Lists[item.ParentList.ID]
      .GetItemByUniqueId(i.UniqueId);

    // execute your code with the system account on the item.
    // adminItem.RoleAssignments.WhatEver
  }
}
```

Please note the use of `SPUserToken.SystemAccount`. This makes the "System Account Token" hack required in SharePoint 2007 obsolete.

For actions on SharePoint objects `SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges` or `WindowsIdentity.Impersonate(System.IntPtr.Zero)` is **not** required.

I've written a blog post that covers this topic: [How To Open a SPSite With thw System Account In SharePoint 2010](http://www.matchpointcommunity.com/blog/Posts/37/how-to-open-a-spsite-with-the-system-account-in-sharepoint-2010).